# How can I dynamically create a validator and bind to a form group?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

currently I am working on an angular project along with a java backend that serves rest api. I want to issue a rest api call and then obtain an object , which is then passed to a custom validator function and then use this validator in the form group. However this is not working as expected because of using RxJs

so here is my rest api call from angular js

```
@Injectable()
export class ModeService {
  get() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Mode>(`${this.config.api}/configuredMode`)
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

my angular component is as follows

```
export class AccountFormComponent implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {
    this.modeService.get().subscribe(
      mode => {
        this.mode = mode;
        this.isConfigurationLoading = false;
        this.emailValidator = emailDomainValidator(this.mode);
      },
      () => {
        this.isConfigurationLoading = false;
      }
    );

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      internal: [
        { value: true, disabled: !this.isTypeEditable },
        [Validators.required]
      ],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      firstName: [
        { value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields },
        [Validators.required]
      ],
      lastName: [
        { value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields },
        [Validators.required]
      ],
      email: [
        { value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields },
        [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.emailValidator]
      ]
}
```

and my template is as follows

```
> <form novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup"
> (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit(formGroup.value)" class="mb-3"
> *ngIf="(!isLoading && !isConfigurationLoading)">   <pc-form-layout>
> 
> </form>
```

and my validator function

```
export function emailDomainValidator(configuredMode: Mode): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    if (configuredMode.propositionType === PropositionType.CMS) {
      const emailId: string = control.value;
      const emailDomain: string = configuredMode.emailDomain;
      if (!emailId.endsWith(emailDomain)) {
        return { invalidEmail: true };
      }
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

However i get an error when i access the application taken from the chrome developer console. what i can make out is in the emailDomainValidator , the configuredMode is undefined, and on calling propositionType I get this issue.

```
VM30160 AccountFormComponent.ngfactory.js:1312 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'propositionType' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM30160 AccountFormComponent.ngfactory.js:1323)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (VM28852 core.js:14891)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM28852 core.js:14005)
    at callViewAction (VM28852 core.js:14351)
    at execComponentViewsAction (VM28852 core.js:14283)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM28852 core.js:14006)
    at callViewAction (VM28852 core.js:14351)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (VM28852 core.js:14309)
    at checkAndUpdateView (VM28852 core.js:14001)
    at callViewAction (VM28852 core.js:14351)
```

Any idea how can fix this issue ??? any help is appreciated and thank you so much

Comment: I believe your 'mode' object is undefined. can you please check. as per your question where is dynamic comes into the picture, because I see everything is fixed validators based on your data. is your form validation rules are coming from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create `FormGroup` after receiving response (api request):

```
export class AccountFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.modeService.get().subscribe(
            mode => {
                this.mode = mode;
                this.isConfigurationLoading = false;

                this.createForm();
            },
            () => {
                this.isConfigurationLoading = false;
            }
        );
    }

    private createForm() {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            internal: [
                {value: true, disabled: !this.isTypeEditable},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            firstName: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            lastName: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            email: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required, Validators.email, emailDomainValidator(this.mode)]
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to firstly create `FormGroup` and then update validators when response arrive then you can try this:

```
export class AccountFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            internal: [
                {value: true, disabled: !this.isTypeEditable},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            firstName: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            lastName: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required]
            ],
            email: [
                {value: '', disabled: !this.showAdminFields},
                [Validators.required, Validators.email]
            ]
        });

        this.modeService.get().subscribe(
            mode => {
                this.mode = mode;
                this.isConfigurationLoading = false;

                this.formGroup.controls.email.setValidators([
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.email,
                    emailDomainValidator(this.mode)
                ]);
                this.formGroup.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity();
            },
            () => {
                this.isConfigurationLoading = false;
            }
        );
    }
}
```